# Unity 2d game Coins will reset every game and wont add up to previous coins collected in the previous game any idea?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Code in the character that get the coin and store it the.... coins can display in the start up main.

Example:

I am game over, I earned 40 coins. I clicked play again and I collected 20 coins.

The 20 coins are the only coins that will display in startup main, the previous 40 coins are gone.

```
function OnTriggerEnter2D( other : Collider2D ) {

if (other.tag == "Coin") {

coins += 1;

PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Coin", coins);

  coinsBegin++;
Destroy(other.gameObject); PlayerPrefs.Save(); } }

function OnGUI () { GUI.Label (Rect (20, 20, 200, 40), "score: " +coins + "");

 }

function GameOver(){

if(coins > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin", coins)){ PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Coin", coins); } Application.LoadLevel("main"); }
```

Comment: Is PlayerPrefs your own object?

Comment: in awake or start of your object that has score, you should do DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject); In that way, that object wont be delete and remake everytime the scene is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

C#:

```
void GameOver(){
   int currentCoin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Coin", 0);

   if(currentCoin < 20){
       Debug.Log("Not enough coins to play !");
   }else{
       currentCoin -= 20;
       PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Coin", currentCoin);
       Application.LoadLevel("main");
   }
}
```